# How to pass array of integer to a stored procedure with comma separated value in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to pass an array of `event_Id` which is `varchar` to a stored procedure, for example: `7607,8110`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]
    @Event_Id VARCHAR(500)
```

How to write the stored procedure to get record with each `event_id`?

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause/36980115#36980115)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Table valued parameters, XML, JSON. Three types *designed* for holding multiple values. Instead you're using an inappropriate type (`varchar`) and then having to unmangle the data inside the stored procedure to obtain the multiple values again.

Comment: With SQL Server 2016 and later, you can use the [STRING_SPLIT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql). You'll need to write T-SQL code for earlier versions such as those in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string).

Comment: As it's not been mentioned as well, you could also consider a user defined table type. Having one for integers is a pretty common "utility" table type to have in a database.